# Android - Could not able to get obb file

Tags: android

I have implemented expansion file as per the below link:
[a link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

When i sign and export application it does not create .obb file and not reduce apk size.
When i run the application it show download failed because resource could not be found.
please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you have used its for accessing the .OBB files. You have to manually create them by using the following command.

```
jobb -d pathToFolder -o fileName.obb -k secret-key -pn packageName -pv 1
```

For more Info [See this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html)

Comment: Can I put images from drawable folder?

Comment: Can u please give me 1 example for putting drawable images into above command and also what to pass in secret key?